# JQuery Drag and Drop Count Content of Drop Area?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, count

Im working on a Jquery project in which the user can drag a 'pill' into a 'cup' and then the amount of pills in the cup can be displayed however ive got a problem with once the pill is in the cup if the user moves the pill it counts it as being dropped again. How do i get the draggable(pill) to be counted once when dropped in the droppable(cup). Is it a case of a for/if loop of storing an array or attaching an identifier to each pill?

here is some of my code 
html

```
       <div id="PillSpace">
       <div class="PillCup"><p>accept: '#Pill'</p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div><br>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div><br>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       <div class="Pill"><p><img src="resources/capsule.png"/></p></div>
       </div>
```

the JQuery is:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $( ".Pill").draggable();

    $( ".PillCup" ).droppable({
        accept: ".Pill",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        over:function(){
            $( ".PillCup" ).find("p").html(count).text;
        },
        out:function(){
        count--;
            $( ".PillCup" ).find("p").html(count).text;
        },
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            count++;
            $( ".PillCup" ).find("p").html(count).text;
        }

    });
});
```

Hope someone can help

thanks guys

Comment: just get count of pills in container with use of class

Comment: how would i implement that roughly?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than inc/decrement the count for each drop, try counting the total number of pills in the container:

```
out: function(){
    count = $(".Pill", ".PillCup").count();
    $( ".PillCup" ).find("p").html(count).text;
},
drop: function( event, ui ) {
    count = $(".Pill", ".PillCup").count();
    $( ".PillCup" ).find("p").html(count).text;
}
```