# jquery counter for draggables (even more!!!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I need further help with the CSS in the following code -this is a continuation of this post:

[jQuery: Counter for draggables (again!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926783/jquery-counter-for-draggables-again)

So, the code below intends to count the number of plates on the tablecloth in such a way that if you put one plate away from the tablecloth, then the counter goes down.

The code more or less works, however, when you click on a plate to drag it, the plate jumps to a different position. The same occurs when you drop the plate on the tablecloth: rather than landing where you want it to land, it lands somewhere else... Very annoying. 
Can anyone advice on how to smooth things out?

```js
$(init);

function init() {



  var j = 0;
  $("#counter").find("h1").html("You keep: " + j);

  $(".fish").draggable({
    addClasses: true,
    refreshPositions: true,
    //When you start dragging you append to body mainly to remove
    // from cloth div
    start: function(e, ui) {
      ui.helper.appendTo('body');
    },
    //You move your out logic to stop. So if the element hasn't been added
    // to cloth, it won't be counter
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      j = $(".cloth  .fish").length;
      j = j + 0;
      $("#counter").find("h1").html("You keep: " + j);
    }

  });

  $(".cloth").droppable({
    accept: ".fish",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      //On drop you append fish to the cloth div so it's counted
      $('.cloth').append(ui.helper.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: ui.helper.offset().top,
        left: ui.helper.offset().left
      }));
      j = $(".cloth  .fish").length;
      j = j + 0;
      $("#counter").find("h1").html("You keep: " + j);

    },


  });


}
```

```css
.mybox {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  maring: auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
#stop-top {
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}
.fish {
  margin: .5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #BAB6B2;
  float: left;
  border: .3em solid #4B027C;
}
.cloth {
  width: 90%;
  height: 210px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5% solid rgba(200, 0, 0, .5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200, 0, 0, .5) 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 0, .5) 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
.ui-draggable-dragging {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='mybox' style='top:5%;height:70%;'>
  <div id="counter" style="margin-left:5%;">
    <h1>You keep: 0</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="cloth"></div>
  <div class="fish" style="margin-left: 5%;"></div>
  <div class="fish"></div>
  <div class="fish"></div>
  <div class="fish"></div>
  <div class="fish"></div>
  <div class="fish"></div>
</div>

<div class='mybox' style='height:20%; background-color:blue;'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " name="buttonSend">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Ok
  </button>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!
Best,

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a way around the problem using native HTML5's capabilities and ditching jQuery. The solution, although imperfect, solves the problem of "jumping" elements when dragging them or dropping them in the "wrong" area of the window.

To sum up: use HTML5 native features to make the relevant elements draggable/droppable. Then use document.getElementById("yourDivId").childNodes.length 
to count the number of children in your droppable area. 
This is done in the following snippet.

```js
//global variable: number of tokens.

var j = 0;

function doFirst(){
 
 
 
 //Set intial variables by ref. to objects in the page.
 token1 = document.getElementById('token1');
 token2 = document.getElementById('token2');
 token3 = document.getElementById('token3');
 token4 = document.getElementById('token4');
 token5 = document.getElementById('token5');
 token6 = document.getElementById('token6');
 //as soon as you start to drag token, fire the user's startdrag.
 token1.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 token2.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 token3.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 token4.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 token5.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 token6.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);
 //Reference tablecloth too.
 tablecloth = document.getElementById('tablecloth');
 // Here you need thre listeners
 // 1. when something enters table cloth do this...
 // this bit function(e){e.preventDefault();} overrides different browsers' default
 // action.
 tablecloth.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
  tablecloth.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
 tablecloth.addEventListener("dragleave",leavecloth,false);
 tablecloth.addEventListener("drop",dropped,false);
 
 contador = document.getElementById('contador'); 
 junk = document.getElementById('junk'); 

 
 middleground.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
 middleground.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){e.preventDefault();},false);
 middleground.addEventListener("dragleave",leavestart,false);
 middleground.addEventListener("drop",droppedout,false);
 
 
}

function startDrag(e){
 
 // stands for an event (something) than happens in your browser.
 // whenever an event occurs the browser stores information about events,
 // e.g. event of moving mouse -stores x-y position. We will have to stores
 // infor with our drop/drag event.
 
 e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.id);
 
 
}

function dropped(e){
 
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
 e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 
 j = document.getElementById("tablecloth").childNodes.length;
 
 contador.innerHTML = j;
}

function droppedout(e){
 
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
 e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  j = document.getElementById("tablecloth").childNodes.length;

 
 contador.innerHTML = j;
}

function leavecloth(e){
 
 leftcloth = 1;
 junk.innerHTML = 'left cloth' + leftstart+leftcloth;
}
function leavestart(e){
 
 leftstart = 1;
 junk.innerHTML = 'left start' + leftstart+leftcloth;
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false); //As soon page loads do this
```

```css
.mybox{
 
 background-color: SkyBlue;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20%;
 
}
.myfooter{
 
 background-color: Yellow;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0%;
 
}
.tablecloth {
 width: 50%;
 height:40%;
 left: 25%;
 position: absolute;
  
 border-radius: 28px;
  
 
 background-color:white;  
 background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(200,0,0,.5) 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,.5) 50%, transparent 50%);
 background-size:20px 20px;
}
  
.fish  {
 margin:.5em;
 font-size:1.2em;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border-radius: 50%;
 
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px; 
 background: #BAB6B2;
 float: left;
 border:.3em  solid #4B027C ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "estilos.css">
 <script src = "acciones.js"></script>

<head>

<body>

  

  <div class = 'tablecloth'  id = 'tablecloth'></div>
  <div class = "mybox" id ='middleground'>
  
  
  <div class = "fish" id = "token1" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class = "fish" id = "token2" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class = "fish" id = "token3" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class = "fish" id = "token4" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class = "fish" id = "token5" draggable="true"></div>
  <div class = "fish" id = "token6" draggable="true"></div>
  
  
  </div>
  <div class = "myfooter">
  <h1>
   <div id = "contador">0</div><br>
   
  </h1>
  <h1>
   <div id = "junk">nothingmuchs.</div><br>
   
  </h1>
  
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Oh! But just a warning: HTML5 drag-and-drop is not supported on mobile devices... Aren't we learning a lot??